# NavMeshAgent.SetDestination слишком долго просчитывает путь

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть такой код

```
public Transform target;
void Update()
{
    if(input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        _agent.SetDestination(target.position);
    }
}
```

Но когда я нажимаю F, агент около 2-3 секунд высчитывает путь до цели. Если я передвину цель и нажму F еще раз - агент остановится и еще 2-3 секунды будет высчитывать новый курс до цели. Нагрузки особой на cpu в эти секунды нет, такое ощущение что он просто лениво считает с низким приоритетом. Как поднять скорость высчитывания или приоритет, или каким то иным образом избежать этих 2-3 секунд задежки перед действием?

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но разве там не такой синтаксис ?
public bool SetDestination(Vector3 target);
как вы туда передаете Transform

Comment: если вы расширили этот метод, то покажите, пожалуйста, логику что внутри

Comment: @Andrey прошу прощения, писал по памяти тут. Конечно, `target.position`

Comment: мне кажется что проблема тут именно в точке.
Что это за цель? Она входит в расчеты при создании NavMesh поверхности ?

Comment: @Andrey Ну эта цель находится в пределах навмеша. Грубо говоря навмеш на плоскости, на той же плоскость цель - куб. Куб не статичен, навмеша на нем нет, он двигается. Задача агента - преследовать куб. При каждом `SetDestination(target.position); `агент несколько секунд думает, только затем устремляется в цели. Навмеш сам по себе большой, сложный, 5 мб весит. Может быть там и есть что считать, но было бы неплохо поднять приоритет, а то нагрузка нулевая на цпу, а считает несколько секунд.

Comment: а просто перемещение в указанную точку работает быстро ? Вы не пробовали? Если вы через Physics.Raycast найдете точку плоскости ?

Comment: @Andrey а что значит "просто перемещение в указанную точку"? `agent.Warp?`

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html  получаете точку таким вот образом. И передаете её в SetDestination

Comment: @Andrey, разницу в скорости вычисления не увидел. Между SetDestination и началом движения так же паузы около 2-3 секунд.

Answer (score 1):

Топаем в [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath.html):

> Description
>
> Sets or updates the destination thus **triggering the
>   calculation** for a new path.
>
> **Note that the path may not become available until after a few frames
>   later**. While the path is being computed, pathPending will be true. If
>   a valid path becomes available then the agent will resume movement.

Иными словами, SetDestionation ведет себя ровно так, как и задумывалось, т.е. просчитывает путь по запросу на, скорее всего, отдельном потоке, чтобы не затормаживать весь процесс.

Если нужно получить путь ровно за 1 кадр, то нужно использовать [NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath.html) и [NavMeshAgent.SetPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.SetPath.html):

```
public Transform target;
private NavMeshAgent agent;

void Start() {...}

void Update()
{
    if(input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();
        agent.CalculatePath(target.position, path);
        if (path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete)
        {
            agent.SetPath(path);
        }
    }
}
```